# Need a SUMIF =SUM(C3-(SUM(E3:N3))) but if E14<0 dont subtract

Tags: google-sheets

I have simple problem which I can't get the right twist on it.

I have a list of **"products"** with their stock in the range of *D3:D13* with a set price, an original stock and a list of **"customers"** in the range of *E3:L3*.

Each customer can take a product and the updated stock currently is: 
**[=SUM(C3-(SUM(E3:L3))) ]**

If we take one person he has his combined cost for how many products he took on E14

If a person pays their cost (E14 > 0) and nulls the products he took currently the updated stock gets rested. That is what I dont want.

Basically: SUM Stock `IF (any of E14:L14) > 0 THEN =SUM(C3-(SUM(E3:N3)))`

Update:
Example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SEssivZ8jCbqedc8TG_PO4uWLN_QzpRQwxJ_bGwHvQg/edit?usp=sharing Hope the link works.

That is basically everything and this works for me currently.
The issue is if a user decides to pay their dept. 
For example User 1 pays. 
Then the currently calculated price for the user (E14) get's nulled and also the cells for how much products they took (E3:E12).

But then because how it is done currently the updated stock gets updated again with the items the user1 took previously because we nulled the E3:E12. But the products where already taken. That is what I want to prevent.

Comment: Is there a formula in C3? or it's a fixed value? | you'd mentioned "THEN =SUM(C3-(SUM(E3:N3)))", what is the content of column N ? | share a screenshot will help to clarify..

Comment: in order to get help, please upload your current data and the result you want.

Comment: I made an example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SEssivZ8jCbqedc8TG_PO4uWLN_QzpRQwxJ_bGwHvQg/edit?usp=sharing Hope the link works. The Stock in C is variable and get's update manually. Updated Stock is then calculated from C - how much each user took. etc. If someone now "pays" and nulls their cell's the updated stock get's reseted that is what I want to prevent

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the sample to your post. Also, you have provided the input, but I suggest you to post the expected output. What would you want to get? What would be the correct result?

Comment: I updated. I can' really provide and "output".

Comment: Welcome. Much easier to calculate E14 by using `sumproduct.`. For example, `=sumproduct($B$3:$B$12,E3:E12)`, then copy across the columns in row 14.

Comment: Are you allowed a helper sheet? Or does it need to be in the same sheet?

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks. I will update that too.

Comment: @Datanovice Helper Sheet would be possible

Comment: @Qpa_ _"The issue is"_ Sorry if I'm a little slow, but I don't understand this or the next paragraph. You need to provide an example (do it manually if need be, and add some comments for clarification) of a successful outcome.

Comment: I hope my explanation of in the sheet helps to clarify. @Tedinoz

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is left to do after `sumproduct`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your Question. Is it still unclear what the issue is?

Comment: Where I am/was confused is the meaning of "Current Stock". Because you tracked "Original stock", I thought that "Current Stock" equals how much stock is available, and that it would/should have nothing to do with whether/when a person might pay their account. However, in your spreadsheet, "Current stock" changes from 14 to 15 when User 1 pays their account. I would suggest making a distinction between the quantity of stock and the debt due. Refer your spreadsheet Cells A16:A18, and E16:18 - this is where/how I would show the debt owing.